# Share singleton instance to shared lib's without exporting it

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

I'm looking for an alternative way to share singleton instances
between the main executable and dll's.

My project currently consists of several static libs which are linked into executables as shown below:

```
  common.lib (holds singletons)
      /             \
     /               \
    v                 \
tools.exe              \
                        V
                  database.lib (holds singletons)
                        |
                        V
                   shared.lib (holds singletons)
                     /
                    /
                   |
                   v
               game.lib (holds singletons)
                   |
                   v           I-- Extension.dll
                server.exe <---I-- Extension.dll (dynamic loaded extensions)
                               I-- Extension.dll
                                       ^
                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
I Extensions loaded through LoadLibrary & dlopen         I
I need to have access to the singletons instantiated in: I
I common.lib, database.lib, shared.lib and game.lib      I
```

The static lib's provide several singletons which i want to expose to dynamic loaded dll's, **which are always binary compatible to the main exe**.

I can't just convert the static libs into dynamic libs because it would break a lot and is too much effort.
My current approach is to turn the static singleton getters:

```
class Log
{
public:
    static Log* instance();
};
```

into something like:

```
class Log { };

__declspec(dllexport) Log* instance();
```

and export the singleton instances though seperate dynamic libs for example:

`common_inst.dll` exports singletons for `common.lib`.

`game_inst.dll` exports singletons for `game.lib`.

This approach works but i'm not satisfied with it.

Is there another crossplatform compatible possibility to share singletons to shared lib's without exporting it through dllexport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't want to have any DLLs or exports in your main code, you can use the virtual functions approach.

Suppose that every extension has an exported function for initialization:

```
DLLEXPORT void InitExtension(MainProgramInfo info);
```

Now you have to add everything your extension wants to access to the passed struct:

```
struct MainProgramInfo {
  Game *game;
  ScriptEngine *script_engine;
  ShaderCompiler *shader_compiler;
  ...
};
```

Note that the classes described here are **not exported**, but their declarations must be available to compile your extensions. In fact, you can even use reduced versions of headers to compile your extensions, but you must make sure that for each class all its virtual methods are declared the same way and in the same order.

A virtual method call requires only:

1. a valid pointer to an object of proper type (at runtime),
2. correct signature of the method (at compile time),
3. an index of the method in the virtual functions table (determined at compile time).

Unlike an ordinary function call, it does **not** need to know the address of the function, therefore you do not need to export virtual functions to call them.

So when your extension receives the pointers in `MainProgramInfo`, it can start calling virtual methods of these objects without having them directly available to the linker. Note that it is not necessary to put every single object into `MainProgramInfo`: you can put only the top-level singleton there, and your extensions can use its virtual functions to get pointers to other objects/singletons:

```
class Game {
  ...
  virtual Renderer *GetRenderer() const;
  virtual ScriptEngine *GetScriptEngine() const;
  virtual ShaderCompiler *GetShaderCompiler() const;
  ...
};
```

This approach works only if your compiler generates the indices of virtual methods the same way both in your main code and in your extensions. The correctness of this approach is **not** guaranteed by C++ standard. It is guaranteed by GCC ABI (see [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7470)). Also, it was used extensively in *Doom 3* in order to implement game mods, so it works on MSVC too.

Answer (score 1):

*In a general case, my advice would be to still convert the static libraries to dynamic ones for the Windows platform and export the functions required*. That said, given the size of the code base you are talking about, I appreciate that this is not viable for you at this stage.

If we turn the question around and ask **"how can you get the functions (or objects) into the extensions?"** and not the current "how do I get the functions (or objects) out of the static libraries?"; I think there may be an interesting alternative. **Akin to Dependency Injection, but for modules**.

Inject the `Log*` into the the extension dlls via an appropriate function `SetLogInstance(Log*)` in the extension dll. In turn, each extension dll will maintain the pointer to the single `Log*`; and each will make the calls to that logger as if it was obtained from an exported function. To make sure that it is available as early as required, this can be added to the initialisation code as the dll is loaded (via. `LoadLibrary`).

There is already something of a similar pattern used in the standard libraries in respect of [`std::set_new_handler`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/set_new_handler) and [`std::terminate_handler`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler) et. al. They are functions that are "injected" into the runtime that allow for custom handlers to be called as required.

There are some additional advantages;

1. Each extension has it's own copy instance of the `Log*` pointer, thus if required, it can be controlled and isolated (for testing or focused monitoring etc.).
2. The instances no longer have to be singletons with respect to the process, only the extensions, so more control is offered to the host to manage the object(s) and their lifetimes.
3. It is easier to evolve the singleton object to a functor of some sort if required (binding techniques can be used to massage the functor as required).

Comment: I like your approach since it's portable and easy to adapt. I prefer the full dynamic linking too, but the codebase i'm talking about has 800000 LoC in static libraries which means it's nearly impossible to fix all linking error which would occur if i change it to dynamic linking, see https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore for details.

Comment: @DenisBlank. At that size, I agree, the change from static to dynamic is going to be a big effort. At that size I would look to inject into the extensions and limit, as many as possible, the dependencies the extensions have on the core and lower their coupling.

Comment: I cannot understand one point. If `Log` class is defined in the main code, you cannot call its method from extension DLL unless the method is exported. Or it is inline, or it is virtual =)

Comment: This is true for all approaches mentioned here. The OP included no definition of what the `Log` class looks like. Independent of how access to the Log object is obtained, its members will need to be accessible as well. To this end, I favor the injection approached with function objects being used (as mentioned in point 3).